Some widgets have started to flicker with UE5.4.2 version
Recently I’ve upgrade the engine of a simple game I’m developing, from 5.3.2 version to 5.4.2 version. I noticed several issues about widgets that flicker both in UI menus and in 3D Widget Components.
Here 2 videos to compare the same scene in UE 5.3.2 and UE 5.4.2:
UE5.3.2 (it’s works fine): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wPpJaqlY08Y
UE5.4.2 (it glitches): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OeDCarbcBQ
Any suggestion to solve this issue?
